# Modeling z on a real in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am making a very simple model of a an output driver which can have 3 output levels. It can also be turned off. What I want to do is model this as a real so I can assign different numbers for the three levels. I am unsure to do to model the 'off' state. I found some discussion about using `inf` or `NaN` to model `z` in a real number, but it doesn't seem like this is a settled argument. So this is a 2 part question:

1) is `NaN` the right way to model `z` on a `real` in system verilog?

2) how do I assign `NaN` in system verilog?  This works:

```
realnum = 0.0/0.0;
```

But it seems like a bit of a kludge to do this. Is there already a defined way to get `NaN`?

The right way to do what I want is probably to use verilog-AMS but I want to avoid using a license for a simulator that supports it for such a simple model.

Edit: To clarify why I want to do this: this model will be a cell view in the top level schematic that I will netlist. I can't do a 2 bit output since the schematic has only one wire.

Comment: Would it just be easier to model your output as a 2-bit signal, if you just want to represent 3 states + off? According to [Asic-World](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/syntax1.html) "Real variables cannot contain 'Z' and 'X'"

Answer (score 0):

A new feature *6.6.7 User-defined nettypes* was added to the 1800-2012 LRM, but I do not think it has been implemented by most vendors yet. In the meantime, you can create your own resolution functions, and manually insert them where needed to convert your real to a 4-state value.